# Do we have event listeners in React Native?

Tags: react-native, event-listener

I have small issue while integrating redux in my react native application. Everything is ok right from creating the action creator and calling the asynchronous network api to dispatching the payload to the app state and then include it as props from mapStatetoProps function. But my problem is, lets say from one screen I initiated the action creator which brings some data from server. Now once the action is performed and the data is received in the action, I need to intimate the screen to do something or show something.

My screen is a class based component and is receiving the data from the mapStatetoProps function but how it should know that data has come and show some alert or do some action. Is there any event listeners we can include in react native apps which works on real devices as well?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-prop/#addlistener---subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) would help?

Comment: Any help on this.